# typescript: tsc is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I am a beginner with type script. I am unable to compile the type script file.

As I hit Ctrl+Shift+B in the VS Code, i get the error "tsc is not recognised"

I used npm while downloading transcript.

```
C:\Users\sramesh>npm install -g typescript
C:\Users\sramesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsserver -> C:\Users\sramesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
C:\Users\sramesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc -> C:\Users\sramesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
C:\Users\sramesh\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- typescript@2.1.5
```

Here is my tasks.json file

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "C:\\Users\\sramesh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\typescript\\bin\\tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running `tsc --init` in your directory? This will create a `tsconfig.json` file in your directory where you can define your configuration. VSCode will also start using this file once it finds it in your root directory.

Check out [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: You're welcome  Edit: Please mark the answer as the solution so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Windows OS and For some reason the marked answer didn't work for me.I tried  `tsc--init` and i was returned the same error.I updated the path variable to `C:\Users\"UserName"\AppData\Roaming\npm` and this worked..

Note:replace Username with your own Username

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue and didn't even showed the version of Typescript after typing  tsc -v.  Even i had to scratch my head for few days and couldn't solve it.

At last i did 4 things.

1. installed latest version of nodejs which is i.e. 8.1.3
2. installed npm which is 5.1.0 ( npm install npm@latest -g)
3. installed typescript 2.4.1   ( npm install -g typescript)
4. as suggested by @Uzair Sajid above. (tsc --init)

Now, I can see the TS version, and also compile the TS code.

Answer (score 3):

After installation, simple solution I tried is just set the path variable in environment variables till folder where npm is installed.

```
C:\Users\"Username"\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

where Username will be your own username.

Then, open cmd, go to npm folder using `cd AppData/Roaming/npm`
and type `tsc` , it will run.
Now just close the cmd and open it again, and type `tsc --version` OR `tsc`, it will run successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I tried using the command line to set the target.

```
tsc first.ts --target ES5
```

This created the first.js( compiled type script in javascript format).I manually moved this file to scripts folder.

Now when i ran the server using `lite-server` command. The browser could find the first.js file and ran the typescript code.

Comment: This is a work around. I am not sure of the tasks.json method. I believe this s a better solution than manually moving the compiled files to script folder. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue on my Windows 10 21H1 desktop by:

1. Install the typescript package globally → `npm install -g typescript`
2. Updating the `Path` environment variable:

   - Search `Environment Variables` in the start menu
   - Select `Edit the system environment variables`
   - Select the `Environment Variables...` button in the `Advanced` section
   - Look in the `System Variables` section for the `Path` variable
   - Double click that variable
   - Select `New...`
   - Enter the location your npm config downloads global packages at. You can find out where by using the `npm list -g` command. For me, it was at `C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm` — be sure to replace `MyUsername` with your username
3. Re/open an active terminal
4. Use the `tsc -v` command to observe the result

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with typescript, 'tsc' not recognized in terminal.

Before I installed typescript with yarn like 'yarn global add typescript',
And then I installed typescript with npm like 'npm install -g typescript' and the issue solved,
Terminal knowing typescript commands and itself.

Maybe this answer would be helpful